# highlight the current week in date_popup drupal

Tags: jquery, css, date, datepicker

Is there any way to highlight the current week starting from Monday to next Sunday ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help when doing it in drupal, but this is how it would be done with jQuery and the datepicker module. Days in the current week will be given the css class `highlight`.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/prBAw/)

```
$(function() {
    var nowDate = new Date();
    nowDate.setHours(0,0,0,0)
    var nowTime = nowDate.getTime();

    var dpFirstDay = 0; //what day is the first day of the week (0 = sunday, 1 = monday...)

    $("#dp").datepicker({
        firstDay: dpFirstDay,
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            var d = new Date(date);
            d.setDate( d.getDate() - (((d.getDay() - dpFirstDay)%7)+7)%7 );
            for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                if (d.getTime() == nowTime)
                    return [true, "highlight"];
                d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
            }
            return [true, ""];
        }
    });
});
```